# Allow Api Access for Android App From Both in Debug and Release Mode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, certificate, android-maps

so, I have published my android app which is using `GoogleMap` that means I indicated release fingerprint together with package name and it is working. Thank you for that.

But it is not working in Debug mode unless I edit fingerprint in `Google APIs Console` which I do not want as I already have millions of downloads (ok 7 or 8 downloads)...

**Is there any way to make it work both on Debug and Release mode?** A way could be adding two fingerprints to the `APIs Console` but... you know...

Comment: separate keys with a ; in the developer console.

Comment: I did but it does no work as i expected/

Comment: It works for me.  The app just has the one generated key from the console.  On the console I have the key from the debug store and my double triple secret key separated by ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the thing is that you can add as many fingerprint and package names as you wish. The pair needs to be on the same line and new pair in new line. Otherwise ti won't even allow you to save the change.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add two signatures and package name combos to the Google Dev console, you could try using same signature (same key store) for both debug and release.